# How to redirect before page processing along with all the sent data?

Tags: 7, redirection

I have a link on my Drupal page. This link points to the page "\node\23423". When user clicks on this link, the user should get redirect to another path "\node\45644".

But this should happen before Drupal starts processing the original path. Also any POST data that is being sent to the original page should be passed to the next redirect page.

Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: _But this should happen before Drupal starts processing the original path_...that would make this un-related to Drupal, wouldn't it?

Comment: Would say no, because node/45644 is supposedly still a drupal path?!

Comment: Well no...how exactly are you going to use Drupal to solve this if the solution has to happen before Drupal gets involved with the request? It's a contradiction in terms, can't happen

Comment: I would suppose, that the OP needs clarification about the approach to what he wants. For me it's not at all clear what he wants though. Best guess would be to change the link in the first place

Comment: Agree @berliner, some clarification would be good

Comment: @Clive: What I meant by that was that Drupal should be able to do all the bootstrapping but should not process the original page (should not create the page array for the original page) but should pass all the data passed to that page as-it-is to the new page.

Comment: Ah ok, you're just looking for a redirect then. If you want to forward `POST` vars you'll need to tackle it at the web server level with a rewrite rule

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (experimental) is something like this (but NOT RECOMMENDED):

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $nid = arg(1);
    if($nid == '23423') {    
      drupal_goto('node\45644');
    }
  }
}


function MY_THEME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if($node->nid == 45644) {
    $old_node = node_load(23423);
    $old_node_view = node_view($old_node);

    $node->content['body'] = $old_node_view['body'];
  }
}
```

Comment: _But this should happen before Drupal starts processing the original path_...the path has very much been processed at both of those points in the request

Comment: @Clive `But this should happen before Drupal starts processing the original path` - Yes, you're right.. My answer is just a suggestion.. I don't why he needs to redirect BEFORE Drupal processes the original path. May be my answer will help him If he decides to just redirect and show another content..

Comment: Problem is, he specifically needs `POST` vars to be sent along, which can't be done with this method

Comment: @Clive then I would use own path (which's been registered by hook_menu) instead of another node path.. And specify my own implementation of generating content..